Why does the Nest decorator work for any request, even when the decorator is not present?
I pointed out the decorator in one place, but it didn't work at all. Then, I connected the guardian to the module as shown in the documentation. Now, the guardian is processing any request.
export const Permissions = (...permissions: PermissionEnum[]) =>
  SetMetadata('permissions', permissions);

@Injectable()
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const requirePermissions = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<
      PermissionEnum[]
    >('permissions', [context.getHandler(), context.getClass()]);
    console.log(requirePermissions, 'requirePermissions');
    if (!requirePermissions) {
      throw new HttpException(
        lang.ru.http_exceptions.forbidden,
        HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
      );
    }

    const user = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    //console.log(context.switchToHttp(), 'switchToHttp');
    //console.log(context.switchToHttp().getRequest(), 'getRequest');
    return false;
  }
}

  @HttpCode(201)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Permissions(PermissionEnum.USER_VIEW)
  @Get('/users')
  getAll(@Query() query: AdminUserQueryDto) {
    return this.adminService.getUsers(query);
  }

@Module({
 ...
  providers: [RoleService, { provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: PermissionGuard }],
  ...
})
export class RoleModule {}

Is this how it should be?
Can you tell me how I can make the guard work only on those routes where the decorator is present?

You are injecting your guard to the module, so it will apply for every controller and every route handler of that module. Instead you can use the @UseGuards decorator for each route handler.
@HttpCode(201)
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Permissions(PermissionEnum.USER_VIEW)
@UseGuards(PermissionGuard)
@Get('/users')
getAll(@Query() query: AdminUserQueryDto) {
  return this.adminService.getUsers(query);
}

If you don't want to use both @Permissions and @UseGuards decorators, you can use the decorator composition option. Using that feature you can combine both decorator and create a new one.
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';

export function PermissionsWithGuard(...permissions: PermissionEnum[]) {
  return applyDecorators(
    Permissions(permissions),
    UseGuards(PermissionGuard),
  );
}

Then in your controller
 @HttpCode(201)
 @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
 @PermissionsWithGuard(PermissionEnum.USER_VIEW)
 @Get('/users')
 getAll(@Query() query: AdminUserQueryDto) {
   return this.adminService.getUsers(query);
 }

Or else you can directly modify your Permission decorator to apply the guard too.
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';
    
export function PermissionsWithGuard(...permissions: PermissionEnum[]) {
  return applyDecorators(
    SetMetadata('permissions', permissions),
    UseGuards(PermissionGuard),
  );
}

